# How to get gRPC DLL for PHP on Windows

Tags: php, grpc

I have PHP 8.3.1 on Windows. I need the gRPC DLL for this version. But I can only find gRPC for PHP up to 8.1: https://pecl.php.net/package/gRPC/1.43.0/windows

This is gRPC 1.43.0.

I tried this version of gRPC (1.43.0) with PHP 8.3.1 and got the following when I ran `php -v`

```
Warning: PHP Startup: grpc: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20210902
PHP    compiled with module API=20230831
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 8.3.1 (cli) (built: Dec 20 2023 14:06:10) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.3.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

How can I get the gRPC DLL for PHP 8.3.1 on Windows?

Comment: Please explain the close vote. This is the first time I've used SO for about 6 months due to ChatGPT and that close vote reminds me why I'm happy I hardly need this website any more. ChatGPT tries to help me without judging and condemning my questions.

Comment: I can't help you with your specific problem (I'm stuck on a similar issue with another extension, tbh), but I'd encourage you to not interpret the close votes as judgmental in any way. As it stands, one close vote was basically "not a programming question" and the other is basically (probably) "asking for software". I'd agree that you aren't asking for a software recommendation, and instead a specific version, and that the extension is related to programming, but the current voters appear to think otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

On the main website, there's a note: https://windows.php.net/

> #### Missing PECL DLLs
>
> You may have already noticed that DLLs for new PECL releases are no longer available for several months. This is because the Windows PECL build machine died, and the team is still working on the long term plan of building DLLs for PECL extensions with a new CI process. We're doing our best to finish that as soon as possible, and keep you up to date.

Basically, you won't have any recent DLLs until they're done with this process.